# How to assign value to variables in a 2Dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

Working on a simple Tic-Tac-Toe Simulator and this is my code for the click event

```cs
private void newGame_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    double randNum = rand.Next(0, 2);

    const int ROWS = 3;
    const int COLS = 3;
    string[,] ticTacToe_2dArray = new string[ROWS, COLS]
    {
        {displayTTT_label1.Text, displayTTT_label2.Text, displayTTT_label3.Text},
        {displayTTT_label4.Text, displayTTT_label5.Text, displayTTT_label6.Text},
        {displayTTT_label7.Text, displayTTT_label8.Text, displayTTT_label9.Text}
    };

    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
        {

            randNum = rand.Next(0, 2);
            if (randNum == 0)
            {
                ticTacToe_2dArray[row, col] = "O";
            }
            else if (randNum == 1)
            {
                ticTacToe_2dArray[row, col] = "X";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Label Grid**

[image: label grid]

Trying to pair the result of the conditional test that assigns an X/O to the next corresponding label.Text variable on my label grid. I am pretty sure the current code is just changing the array variable to X/O instead of the label.Text value.

Comment: The code you have is getting a `string` from each `Label` and putting that in the array. The array knows nothing about the `Labels`. If you expect to be able to change a `Label` via the array then the array must contain the `Labels`, not `strings`. You would then get the appropriate `Label` from the array by index and set its `Text` property.

Comment: DO NOT CALL `new Random()` EVERY TIME YOU NEED A RANDOM NUMBER. Initialize the `Random` class **ONCE** and only once and then use it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are storing copies of strings from your text boxes and then updating the copies.

What you need to do is store the text boxes in the dictionary and assign the "X" and "O" strings to their text properties.

```
private void newGame_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    double randNum = rand.Next(0, 2);

    const int ROWS = 3;
    const int COLS = 3;

    TextBox[,] ticTacToe_2dArray = new TextBox[ROWS, COLS]
    {
        {displayTTT_label1, displayTTT_label2, displayTTT_label3},
        {displayTTT_label4, displayTTT_label5, displayTTT_label6},
        {displayTTT_label7, displayTTT_label8, displayTTT_label9}
    };

    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
        {

            randNum = rand.Next(0, 2);
            if (randNum == 0)
            {
                ticTacToe_2dArray[row, col].Text = "O";
            }
            else if (randNum == 1)
            {
                ticTacToe_2dArray[row, col].Text = "X";
            }

        }
    }
}
```